# Dashed area for a function

Tags: tikz-pgf

Good morning,
Im trying to reproduce this photo. [image]

This is my code

```
        \begin{tikzpicture}[holdot/.style={circle,draw,fill=white,inner sep=1.5pt}]
        \draw[help lines, color=gray, dashed] (-4,-2) grid (4,4);
        \draw[->,ultra thick] (-4,0)--(4,0) node[right]{$x$};
        \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-2)--(0,4) node[above]{$y$};
        \path[pattern color=red,scale=1,pattern=north east lines] (0,0) -- (2.7,0) --(2.7,3.7)-- 
 (0,1)--(0,0) ; 
    \draw[thick,blue,domain=-1.57:1.57,samples=200] (-3,3) node[anchor=north west] {$f(x)=\arcsin(x)$} plot({sin(\x r)},\x);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Could you please help me to finish this. Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interchanging `x` and `y` coordinates is a good way to draw the graph of inverse functions. Here you are!

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=2]
\fill[blue!30] plot[domain=0:pi/2] ({sin(\x r)},\x) |- cycle;
\fill[red!30] plot[domain=0:-pi/2] ({sin(\x r)},\x) |- cycle;
\draw[->] (-1.5,0)--(1.5,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-pi/2-.5)--(0,pi/2+.5) node[above]{$y$};
\draw[dashed] 
(1,pi/2)--(0,pi/2) node[left]{$\frac{\pi}{2}$} 
(-1,-pi/2)--(0,-pi/2) node[right]{$-\frac{\pi}{2}$}
(1,pi/2)--(1,0) node[below]{$1$} 
(-1,-pi/2)--(-1,0) node[above]{$-1$}
;

\draw[teal,thick,smooth] plot[domain=-pi/2:pi/2] ({sin(\x r)},\x);
\path (-1,1) node[teal]{$f(x)=\arcsin(x)$} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would never have think about using fill like that, very clever!

Comment: @blackMild Thank you very much

Comment: @AH it's better trying guess and understand the meaning of code, look at PGF/TikZ manual https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf, so you can apply for other situations. Try this `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]  
\fill[yellow] (0,0)
plot[domain=0:1] (\x,\x*\x) -- cycle;    
\draw[dashed] 
(1,1)--(1,0) node[below]{$1$} 
(1,1)--(0,1) node[left]{$1$};
\draw[->] (-1,0)--(1.5,0) node[below right]{$x$};  
\draw[->] (0,-1)--(0,1.5) node[below left]{$y$};  
\draw[teal,thick,smooth] 
plot[domain=-.8:1.4] (\x,\x) plot[domain=-1:1.2] (\x,\x*\x);  \end{tikzpicture}
`